# How to Store Monte Carlo Simulation Outputs Within a reactive() Function In Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, montecarlo

I have been working on a side project that involves a simple shiny app that allows users to input the parameters of a dice roll for a board game then have the code preform 10,000 rolls with those parameters and present the average of the rolls. I have a basic code that successfully makes this happen but I am struggling how to make it into a shiny app to make accessible to others.

The issue I face is that in the server part of the shiny code I do not know how to store the intermediate results within a single reactive() function. Is there a local storage option that works with a repeating function?

The code I am using is:

```
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("10,000 Roll Simulator"),

   # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         numericInput(inputId = "num_tac", label = "TAC", 
                      value =1 , min = 1, max = 20),
         numericInput(inputId = "num_def", label = "DEF", 
                      value =1 , min = 1, max = 10),
         numericInput(inputId = "num_arm", label = "ARM", 
                      value =0 , min = 0, max = 10)
      )
   )
)

server <- function(input, output){
 data()<- reactive({
   One_roll<- function(){dice <- sample(1:6, size = input$num_tac, replace = TRUE)
   return(sum((dice >= input$num_def)-input$num_arm))
   sims<-replicate(10000, One_roll()}
output$stats <- renderPrint({mean(data())})
}
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few issues with your code :

- `data()<-` is not allowed. Use `data<-` instead then call it with `data()`
- Using `input$` inside a function is definitely not the right way to pass parameters

This is a modified server function where the One_roll function is defined outside the reactive, but called inside, with input passed as parameters:

```
server <- function(input, output){
  One_roll<- function(num_tac,num_def,num_arm){
    dice <- sample(1:6, size = num_tac, replace = TRUE)
    sum((dice >= num_def)-num_arm)
  }
  data<- reactive(replicate(10000, One_roll(input$num_tac,input$num_def, input$num_arm )))
  output$stats <- renderPrint(mean(data()))
}
```

And also you need a `textOutput` in the `ui` function to call the renderText for example:

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("10,000 Roll Simulator"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput(inputId = "num_tac", label = "TAC", 
                   value =1 , min = 1, max = 20),
      numericInput(inputId = "num_def", label = "DEF", 
                   value =1 , min = 1, max = 10),
      numericInput(inputId = "num_arm", label = "ARM", 
                   value =0 , min = 0, max = 10)
    ), mainPanel = textOutput("stats")
  )
)
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much! I did not realize that I needed to/ could set up the equations in the server section ahead of the reactive equation. --Thank you!

Comment: @Nathan you could as well define the function right before using it, but it would be created each time your variable changes, and you couldn't use it in another part of your server function

Answer (score 0):

You could also save all the user entered data into a static variable first and then use them as normal variables.

```
server <- function(input, output) {

temp <- reactive({

  tac <- input$num_tac

  def <- input$num_def

  arm <- input$num_arm

  One_roll <- function(tac, def, arm) {

    dice <- sample(1:6, size = tac, replace = TRUE)

    sum((dice >= def) - arm)

  }

  data <- replicate(10000, One_roll(tac, def, arm))

  #remember to print the data again so the results will be saved to temp

  data

})

output$stats <- renderPrint({

  mean(temp())

})

}
```

Comment: It might be a bit confusing for users not familiar with functions to use same variable names for storing the input and for arguments name in function definition.